# Adding controls to Excel workbook, via VSTO, resets everything in VBA

Tags: vba, .net-4.0, vsto, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have a VSTO Excel Addin solution which exposes certain methods to VBA through a ComVisible interface. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064902/call-excel-add-in-function-from-excel-workbook-vsto) for a sample implementation. I am using VSTO 4 and Excel 2007/2010 for this.
Certain methods of the exposed interface insert a control (button, combo box or a Winform UserControl) when called from VBA. The method executes properly and inserts the control on the sheet as well.

```
public void AddButtonControl(string strControlName)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet nativeWorksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet vstoWorksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(nativeWorksheet);

    vstoWorksheet.Controls.AddButton(nativeWorksheet.Range["A1", "E5"], strControlName);
}
```

Now as soon as the control is inserted in the workbook, all the variables declared in VBA are reset. All code goes back to the state as if it were never executed.

My solution and an Excel workbook are shared [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=3fd2a9f3d09c1b1e&resid=3FD2A9F3D09C1B1E!114)

Just build the solution and open the workbook SampleTest.xlsm
Click "Check string value", a message box saying "Default Text" would be displayed.
Click on button - "Add Button Dynamically". A button would be inserted at the top of the sheet. and a message saying - "Assigning text to string: Sample Text" would be displayed.
Now click "Check string value" again. It should have displayed "Sample Text" but a blank message box is displayed.

Any suggestions/workarounds are welcome.

Comment: Adding the button is likley triggering a recompile of the workbook's VBA Project: this always results in global variables being reset. You could maybe consider using a shape instead of a button, and setting its "OnAction" property to whatever macro you need it to run.

Comment: It's not just about a button. What I am actually doing is inserting some custom controls on the workbook for creating a dashboard. The control itself contains multiple items which work together, even share a significant amount of data. The idea was to reduce the data transfers from Excel to addin, in turn reducing the conversion required for the process, as the data could be quite huge.